# How to force clang to use some library by default?

Tags: c++, build, clang, llvm, clang++

I build *clang* by *clang* against *libc++*, *libc++abi*, *compiler-rt* in the following steps:

- To download (and update) *llvm* and sub-projects I use the following script:

  ```
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
  cd llvm/tools
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk clang/tools/extra
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk lldb
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lld/trunk lld
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/polly/trunk polly
  cd ../projects/
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk compiler-rt
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libunwind/trunk libunwind
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/openmp/trunk openmp
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/trunk libcxxabi
  svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk libcxx
  ```
- First of all I build *llvm*, *clang*, *libunwind* against *libgcc* and *libstdc++* using *gcc* and install them in `/usr/local`. In all the following steps except the last one I use this fresh `clang`/`clang++`.
- Then I separately build *libunwind*, both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions (they are essential, as will be further, because *asan* needs the 32-bit versions of some libraries during the final compilation of the whole project tree) and install it in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib32` correspondingly (also I update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` respectively).
- Build *libcxxrt* ABI library both 32-bit and 64-bit versions and install them properly.
- Build *libcxx* against *libcxxrt* both 32-bit and 64-bit versions and install them properly.
- Then build *libc++abi* against *libc++* both 32-bit and 64-bit versions and install them properly.
- Then build *libc++* against *libc++abi* both 32-bit and 64-bit versions and install them properly over the previous version linked to *libcxxrt*.
- After all I build the whole project tree against *libc++*, *libc++abi*, *libunwind*, *compiler-rt* and install it over old *clang* in `/usr/local`.

(I am almost sure that no step is redundant here.)

At the final step I have a problem: I have to add extra parameters to the linker (I add them to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`) `-lunwind` and `-lc++abi`. Moreover, every time I use the resulting `clang++` with `-stdlib=libc++` and *compiler-rt* (or, equally, `CLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++` and `CLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt`) in my projects I have to do it over and over. It annoying. Say *Qt Creator* generated project's `CMakeLists.txt` should be corrected by hand or by `cmake-gui`.

How to make `clang` driver to automatically specify these options to `ld` at runtime? Is there something similar to `RPATH` mechanism? Or is there some specific *CMake* variable (specified before *llvm* building process) to achieve desired behaviour?

Can I use `RPATH` for my purposes?

Surely I don't want to make some *bash*-script like wrappers (similar to `clang++-libc++`) to specify additional parameters. I want the libraries to be hardcoded somewhere in the `clang` binary itself.

Comment: If you're on Linux, just put something like `INPUT(libc++.so.1 -lc++abi -lunwind)` into your `libc++.so`

Comment: @SK-logic It is a good workaround. Very likely I have to use it, but in addition I want to find a way though configuration of *llvm* build.

Comment: I don't think there is a magic variable to do this (at least not something that can be found at quick glance), but it certainly can be done by patching lib/Driver/Tools.cpp, various standard libraries are hardcoded there.

Comment: Now I think I can merge `libc++.a`, `libc++abi.a` and `libunwind.a` into a single `libc++.a` file. But how to deal with `*.so`?

Comment: yes if you  using on Linux,put INPUT(libc++.so.1 -lc++abi -lunwind) into your libc++.

Comment: @abdul Simply as a text in text editor? Or in some section (`*.so` is binary file)?

Comment: into your *.so binary file

Comment: @abdul `libc++.so` is a symbolic link to `libc++.so.1`, which is symbolic link to `libc++.so.1.0`, which in turn is ELF shared object.

Comment: @Orient, replace the symlink with a text file with that one line in it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of workarounds have been suggested. I ended up with the following workaround:

```
mkdir build
cd build
# backup:
cp -vaf /usr/local/lib/libc++.{a,so.1.0} /usr/local/lib/libc++abi.{a,so.1.0} /usr/local/lib/libunwind.{a,so.1.0} .
clang -shared -fPIC -pthread -o fuse.so -Wl,--whole-archive libc++.a libc++abi.a libunwind.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl -lm
ar x libc++.a
ar x libc++abi.a
ar x libunwind.a
ar rc fuse.a *.o
sudo chown root:root fuse.*
sudo cp -vaf fuse.so /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -svf /usr/local/lib/libc++.so.1 /usr/local/lib/fuse.so
sudo cp -vaf fuse.a /usr/local/lib/
sudo mv -vf /usr/local/lib/libc++.a /usr/local/lib/libc++.a.bak
sudo ln -svf /usr/local/lib/libc++.a /usr/local/lib/fuse.a
```

It merges all the libraries used (`libc++`, `libc++abi` and `libunwind`) into the one single `*.a` or `*.so` file. Then `libc++.a` and `libc++.so` are replaced with (links to) resulting assemblied files, saving a previous versions for possible backup.

It works perfectly for me.

But this is not the answer. Maybe someday `clang` will not have such a problem right from the box.