# Structured bindings implementation underground and std::tuple

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, stdtuple, structured-bindings

Is it true, that [structured bindings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0217r3.html) in `clang` (I use recently builded `clang version 4.0.0 (trunk 282683)`) are implemented using some stuff from `<tuple>`, like braces-init lists may use stuff from `<initializer_list>`?

I wrote simple code just to play with some of [latest features implemented](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html):

```
struct S { int a; char b; double c; };
auto [a, b, c] = S{1, '2', 3.0};
using A = decltype(a);
using A = int;
using B = decltype(b);
using B = char;
using C = decltype(c);
using C = double;
```

So far so good, but when I add `const` qualifier before `auto`:

```
struct S { int a; char b; double c; };
const auto [a, b, c] = S{1, '2', 3.0};
using A = decltype(a);
using A = int const;
using B = decltype(b);
using B = char const;
using C = decltype(c);
using C = double const;
```

I get a strange error description:

```
In file included from /home/user/test/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/user/test/./test.hpp:4:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:193:
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:29:14: fatal error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::tuple_size<S>'
    : public tuple_size<_Tp> {};
             ^
/home/user/test/main.cpp:110:16: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::tuple_size<const S>' requested here
    const auto [a, b, c] = S{1, '2', 3.0};
               ^
/usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:25:50: note: template is declared here
template <class _Tp> class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY tuple_size;
                                                 ^
```

I.e. there is interaction with accidentally included `<tuple>`.

I know that structured bindings are partially implemented in `clang`, but either way it is interesting how `<tuple>` may be related to them?

Should I include `<tuple>` to use structured bindings?

#### Additional:

`auto`, `auto &` and `auto &&` works, but `auto const` and `auto const &` not.

Comment: Implemenation using `std::tie` would be kind of natural to me...

Comment: @W.F. Another way is to make the feature built-in.

Comment: I mean underlying implemenation :) but I know it doesn't answer your question...

Comment: See [LWG 2770](http://wg21.link/LWG2770). You can expect this to be fixed before C++17 ships.

Comment: @W.F. `tie` would be utterly unnatural to me, but whatever.

Comment: @T.C. got your point... thanks

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work myself, I'm using `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)`, so clang 8? You said clang 4, what does that mean? I cannot get structured bindings to compile at all. Can you indicate how you got clang to compile this (I've got the makefile set to C++1z)

Comment: @johnbakers `clang --version | head -1` give `clang version 4.0.0 (trunk 282862)` at the moment

Comment: @johnbakers on *Ubuntu 16.04* append next two lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`: `deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main` `deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial main`. Then `apt-get update`. Then `apt-get install clang-4.0`.

Comment: @johnbakers Another way is to build `clang` from trunk by yourself. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716684/) I wrote an algorithm (it can be reduced to the first couple of bullets for your case).

Comment: thanks for the pointers (no pun intended!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, structured binding uses `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` as customization points. The basic rule is, roughly,

1. first handle built-in arrays;
2. then check `tuple_size<T>::value`;
3. if that fails then check if the class has all public data members.

For step #2 to work reliably, `tuple_size` needs to be SFINAE-friendly, but `tuple_size<cv T>` isn't currently required to be SFINAE-friendly. Hence [the bug](http://wg21.link/LWG2770).

Comment: Interesting how looks like an equivalent (pseudo)code (like one exsistent for ranged *for*-loop) of such a SFINAE-based algorithm. Why if `<tuple>` is not included, there is no hard error here? It's strange. Because if there is no symbol `std::tuple_size` then there definitely should be hard error here but it is not the case. Whereas violation of SFINAE-friendlieness of `tuple_size<cv T>` gives hard error.

Comment: @Orient It's a special core language construct; it doesn't have to obey (normal) SFINAE rules. And arguably not triggering a hard error on missing `tuple_size` makes sense because freestanding implementations need not have `tuple_size` at all.